# Matching 2 words in 2 lines and +1 to the matching pair?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Ive got a variable `list` which is always being fed a new line
And variable `words` which is a big list of single word strings

Every time `list` updates I want to compare it to `words` and see if any strings from `words` are in `list`
If they do match, lets say the word *and* is in both of them, I then want to print `"And : 1"`. Then if next sentence has that as well, to print `"And : 2"`, etc. If another word comes in like *The* I want to print +1 to that

So far I have split the incoming text into an array with `text.split()` - unfortunately that is where im stuck. I do see some use in `[x for x in words if x in list]` but dont know how I would use that. Also how I would extract the specific word that is matching

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) object to keep a tally for each of the words that you are tracking. To improve performance, use a `set` for your word list (you said it's big). To keep things simple assume there is no punctuation in the incoming line data. Case is handled by converting all incoming words to lowercase.

```py
from collections import Counter

words = {'and', 'the', 'in', 'of', 'had', 'is'}    # words to keep counts for
word_counts = Counter()
lines = ['The rabbit and the mole live in the ground',
         'Here is a sentence with the word had in it',
         'Oh, it also had in in it. AND the and is too']

for line in lines:
    tracked_words = [w for word in line.split() if (w:=word.lower()) in words]
    word_counts.update(tracked_words)
    print(*[f'{word}: {word_counts[word]}'
            for word in set(tracked_words)], sep=', ')
```

**Output**

```
the: 3, and: 1, in: 1
the: 4, in: 2, is: 1, had: 1
the: 5, and: 3, in: 4, is: 2, had: 2
```

Basically this code takes a line of input, splits it into words (assuming no punctuation), converts these words to lowercase, and discards any words that are not in the main list of words. Then the counter is updated. Finally the current values of the relevant words is printed.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
sentence = "Hello this is a sentence"
list_of_words = ["this", "sentence"]

dict_of_counts = {}                     #This will hold all words that have a minimum count of 1.

for word in sentence.split():           #sentence.split() returns a list with each word of the sentence, and we loop over it.
    if word in list_of_words:
        if word in dict_of_counts:      #Check if the current sentence_word is in list_of_words.
            dict_of_counts[word] += 1   #If this key already exists in the dictionary, then add one to its value.
        else:
            dict_of_counts[word] = 1    #If key does not exists, create it with value of 1.
        print(f"{word}: {dict_of_counts[word]}") #Print your statement.
```

The total count is kept in `dict_of_counts` and would look like this if you print it:
`{'this': 1, 'sentence': 1}`

Comment: So I have done this and edited it a bit, though it seems to skip over `if word in dict_of_counts:` even if the word is in the list. I cant seem to get it to complete the if statement and will always go to the else, or it will just go to the `for word in sentence.split():` before restarting at the top

Answer (score 0):

You should use `defaultdict` here for the fastest processing.

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_string = "This is an input string"
list_of_words = ["input", "is"]
counts = defaultdict(int)

for word in input_string.split():
    if word in list_of_words:
        counts[word] +=1
```